# select rows where counts > 0 in few tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with the following tables:

> Information, red, hourse, green

In **Information table** have all the products that I sell in the store. The rest of the tables, have the inventory of that product as below :

Example:

++ **`Information`** table:

**id, name, price**

> 01, test, 100$
>
> 02, testagain, 50$
>
> 03, t03, 30$
>
> 04, t04, 50$
>
> 05, t05, 122$

++ **`Red`** table:

**id, sid, counts**

> 01, 01, 50

This means that "test" product, in Red warehouse and I have 50 pieces.

++ **`Green`** table:

**id, sid, counts**

> 01, 03, 20

++ **`Hourse`** table:

**id, sid, counts**

> 01, 02, 150

Can I select from `information` tables, only what I have in my Warehouses (Red, Green, hourse) with the `counts > 0`

In our example, it's show only: `test (id 01), testagain (id 02) and t03 (id 03)` But not displayed id's 04 and 05.

Is it possible using SQL?

Thank you, Sorry about the mess!

Comment: Don't have separate tables for the different warehouses. Have one common table, with a column specifying warehouse.

Comment: This database design is really bad. Please make this what jarlh said. It will save you lots of time in future.

Comment: @jarlh Thank you but I save the location and the side of the product. also, I have the same product in few warehouses...

Answer (score -1):

using left join

```
select a.id, a.name, isnull(b.counts,0)
 from information as a
left join (select * from red
   union all
    select * from green
   union all
    select * from Hourse 
) b on a.id= b.sid
```

Comment: But that will select all of information table, he asked only what appears on the other tables. You should use INNER JOIN

Comment: @sagi but display counts column of other table. And inner join to display same record of both table so here to need left outer join.

Comment: I understand, but he didn't ask for the count, just to display those with count>0(which means that they have atleast one record on one of the tables)

Comment: @sagi so not given minus point . He didn't given output columns

Answer (score -1):

check this query this may work.

```
    select * from information i left join red r 
    on i.id = r.sid 
    left join green g 
    on i.id = g.sid 
    left join hourse h 
    on i.id = h.sid 
    group by
    i.id having count > 0
```

Comment: yes Ramirez want everything from information table right.

Comment: No, only rows where a matching row exists in any of the three other tables.